# Is data written to a OutputStream safe to assume always valid?

Tags: java, file-io, outputstream

Is there any potential for Java/Android to incorrectly write data with an OutputStream?
I occasionally have reports from users that generated files don't open, and upon inspection, they seem to go "wrong" somewhere random in the middle.

It's very, very rare.

Files are just a bunch of numbers written through many different iterations of loops, with helper functions like:

```
public static void writeShortToOutputStream(short value, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write((value >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write(value & 0xFF);
}

public static void writeIntToOutputStream(int value, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write((value >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write((value >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write((value >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write(value  & 0xFF);
}
```

Is there any chance there can be interruptions, hiccups, etc where a byte gets missed or skipped or something?
This is through a GZipOutputStream btw

I just now changed the helper functions above to instead assemble these Short/Int/Float bytes into a `byte[]` and then I call `outputStream.write(byteArr, 0, 4);` as an attempt to make sure all data is written at once, per Short/Int/Float that is.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? What is the rule that would tell you if a file is "valid" or not"? What do your users mean that the files "don't open"? Where is the code that tries to "open" them, and what does "opening" them actually entail (I assume you are actually talking about reading and parsing their contents)? What errors are they reporting? Are the files *found* in the first place? Were they written by your code? Are they being "opened" by your code? Do you have any example of an *actual file* that causes the problem?

Comment: **Please** read [mre]. It's not even remotely possible to analyze the problem usefully from this perspective. These two samples of the code tell us effectively nothing about what the program is actually doing in order to write the file. And what do you even mean by "Java/Android" in the first place? Android is a platform, not another programming language. *Are you able to reproduce* the problem on other platforms? Are you able to reliably reproduce it on Android in the first place? If not, how on earth should anyone else be able to figure out what is going on?

Comment: In theory hardware problems can cause all kinds of artifacts like that, depending on what medium you write to (network, disk, ...). But it's significantly more common that some bug in your code shows up only in some rare corner cases (like a bug only happening when a specific message crosses some buffer size boundary or the like). So I'd first investigate towards that direction before assuming hardware problems.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel im not asking for help for a specific issue, im asking for anecdotal and theoretical discussion

Comment: Is there **any**? Sure. Is it **likely**? Less so. Will the issue be difficult to find? Depends on  the file you're writing and how easy it is to debug/reverse-engineer its content *(think: oh, every time I write a Foo's bytes with status XYZ everything it hoses up the following data)*. A format-aware file viewer or data-aware file disassembler/decoder may be useful.

Comment: @yesbutmaybeno: then your question is off-topic, almost by definition. SO is for asking *specific* questions about *specific* tech problems that can be solved. If you want story-times, you'll have to find another platform.

Comment: @JoachimSauer your comment is off topic

Comment: @yesbutmaybeno SO is pretty much for specific issues. There's no real way to answer the question, but as said: it's far more likely it's a programming issue and not  spurious data loss.

Comment: If the question is "what can cause file writing to fail?" then that's a general computer-science question; it isn't clear what the supposed tie is to the language, let alone the use of `GZipOutputStream` etc. But if you want to know what happened... there's some code, somewhere in the system, that actually handles the `IOException`, right?

Answer (score 2):

When writing to files or some external stream or file you can not guarantee that the writing won't be interrupted. The disk could be full, the network can go down, another process could lock files, your application could crash (probably for unrelated reasons) or the power could go down on the system. Any of that, and other reasons, could cause the writing to be interrupted or the file to be corrupted or improperly closed.